# C++ Passing Struct Address

Tags: c++, function, pointers

Im a little bit confused about passing structs into functions. I understand pointers and everything.

But for instance:

```
struct stuff
{
   int one
   int two 
};

int main{
    stuff fnc;
    fnc.two = 2;
    fnc.one = 1;
    multiply(&fnc);

}

void multiply(const stuff * pm){
    cout << pm->one * pm->two;
}
```

First of all....am i even doing this right.
And second of all, why do we use the address operator when we pass the function, but use the * pointer operator in the actual function call?
Im confused?

Comment: Have you compiled this code and run it?  What was the output?

Comment: This was jsut an example, I was mainly concerned with WHY you use & when passing into a function, and why you use * in the actual function. Got me confused

Comment: I would say that you _don't_ understand pointers if you're asking this. Your terminology is nowhere near correct. You are not "passing a function" and you are not using "*" in the function call (you're using it in the function definition). Are you confused at the overloading of "*" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, your code is compilable other than the missing semicolons in the defintion of `struct stuff`. I'm not quite sure exactly what you're asking about passing the function and the actual function call, but I think you're wondering why the function call uses `&fnc`, but the parameter is `stuff *pm`? In that case, the `fnc` variable declared is a plain `stuff`. It is not a pointer, it refers to the actual instance of that struct.

Now the `multiply` function is declared as taking a `stuff*` -- a pointer to a `stuff`. This means that you can't pass `fnc` directly -- it's a `stuff` and `multiply` expects a `*stuff`. However, you can pass `fnc` as a `stuff*` by using the & operator to take the address, and `&fnc` is a valid `stuff*` that can be passed to `multiply`.

Once you're in the `multiply` function, you now have a `stuff*` called `pm`. To get the `one` and `two` variables from this `stuff*`, you use the pointer to member operator (`->`) since they are pointers to a `stuff` and not a plain `stuff`. After obtaining those values (`pm->one` and `pm->two`), the code then multiples them together before printing them out (`pm->one * pm->two`).

Comment: Yes this is precisely what I was asking. Thanks, my wording was terribly messed up in my question lol

Comment: I think this is the only thing that actually answers the question.

Answer (score 2):

The `*` and `&` operands mean different things depending on whether they describe the type or describe the variable:

```
int  x;        // x is an integer
int* y = &x;   // y is a pointer that stores the address of x
int& z =  x;   // z is a reference to x
int  a = *y;   // a in an integer whose value is the deference of y
```

Your `pm` variable is declared as a pointer, so the `stuff` type is modified with `*`. Your `fnc` variable is being used (namely for its address), and thus the variable itself is marked with `&`.

You can imagine the above examples as the following (C++ doesn't actually have these, so don't go looking for them):

```
int x;
pointer<int> y = addressof(x);
reference<int> z = x;
int a = dereference(y);
```

It the difference between describing a type and performing an operation.

Answer (score 1):

In

```
void multiply(const stuff * pm){
    cout << pm->one * pm->two;
}
```

The `stuff * pm` says that pm is an *address* of a stuff struct.

The

```
&fnc
```

says "the address of `fnc`".

When a variable is declared like:

> stuff *pm;

it tells us that `pm` should be treated like an address whose underlying type is `stuff`.

And if we want to get the address of a variable `stuff fnc`, we must use

> &fnc

Answer (score 0):

Sure, this would work, aside from your erroneous `main` function definition.

The reason why this works is because when you use the unary `&` operator, it essentially returns a pointer to the operand, so in your case, `fnc`, which is of type `stuff`, if you did `&fnc`, that would return a `stuff *`. This is why the `multiply` function must take in a `stuff *`.

```
struct stuff
{
   int one, two;
};

int main(int argc, const char* argv[]) {
    stuff fnc;
    fnc.two = 2;
    fnc.one = 1;
    multiply(&fnc); //passes a pointer to fnc
}

void multiply(const stuff * pm){
    //the "*" operator is the multiplication operator, not a pointer dereference
    cout << pm->one * pm->two; //->one is equivalent to (*pm).one
}
```

Comment: Ya thanks, it was just an example I threw together. I was just confused at the usage of * and & operators

Answer (score 0):

You need the address of operator so you can get the address of the object, creating a pointer, which the function expects.  The '*' in the parameter list is not a pointer operator, it simply says that the variable is a pointer.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct. In the main, you successfully create a 'stuff' object and set its values. Then, you pass a constant address to the object into the function multiply. The multiply function then uses that address to access the two variables of the structure to output the multiplication of the variables.

The * in "const stuff * pm" means that it takes a constant pointer to a stuff object.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example of what you would like to see.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
struct stuff
{
   int one;
   int two;
};

void multiply(stuff* pm)
{
    cout << pm->one * pm->two;
}
int main()
{
    stuff* fnc = new stuff;
    fnc->two = 1;
    fnc->one = 2;
    multiply(fnc);
    delete fnc;
    cin.ignore(1000, 10);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of syntactic errors in your program, but other than that, the basic idea is fine. Here are the syntax problems I had to fix before your program would compile:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct stuff
{
   int one;
   int two; 
};

void multiply(const stuff * pm) {
    cout << pm->one * pm->two;
}

int main() {
    stuff fnc;
    fnc.two = 2;
    fnc.one = 1;
    multiply(&fnc);

}
```

To answer your questions about difference between the '&' (address of) operator and the '*' (pointer dereference) operator though, we just need to think about the types you're passing in to the function.

Take the function multiply:

```
void multiply(stuff *fnc) {
...
}
```

In the definition of this function, you are describing something that takes a pointer to a stuff struct. In that first line, you aren't saying you are dereferencing that object, just that you are expecting a pointer to a stuff object.

Now when you call multiply:

```
stuff fnc;
multiply(&fnc);
```

You are using the '&' (address of) operator to get a pointer to the object. Since the multiply function expects a pointer, and you have the plain old object, you need to use the & operator to get a pointer to give to the multiply function.

Perhaps it is clearer to think call it like this:

```
stuff fnc; //The actual object
stuff* fnc_ptr = &fnc; //A pointer to a stuff object, initialized to point at fnc created above
multiply(fnc_ptr); //Call the function with the pointer directly
```

Answer (score 0):

**Following code will tell you about the pointer illustration**

> A struct address is passed into the function named multiply and this
>   function perform some operations with the element of the passed
>   structure and store the result in the result variable.

*you can see here clearly that the result variable is previously zero then after passing the address of the structure to the function multiply the result variable value gets updated to value **6**. this is how pointer works.*

```
#include <iostream.h>



struct stuff
{
   int one;
   int two ;
   int result;
};
void multiply(stuff *pm);
int main(){
    stuff fnc;
    fnc.two = 2;
    fnc.one = 3;
    fnc.result = 0;
    multiply(&fnc);
    cout<<fnc.result;

return 0;

}

void multiply(stuff *pm)
{
    pm->result = pm->one * pm->two;
}
```